# python regex : .format(string) in .sub with group

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

In python 2.7 and with the module `re`

I have this string

```
cat description:
 cat age: 10
 cat size: 20
 other properties
end cat description:
```

I try to get

```
cat description:
 cat age: 30
 cat size: 40
 other properties
end cat description:
```

for this I try

```
pattern = re.compile(
    (
        r"(cat description.*cat age: )\d+"
        "(.*cat size: )\d+"
        "(.*end cat description:)"
    ),
    re.MULTILINE
)
age = '30'
size = '40'
return pattern.sub(
    r"\1{}\2{}\3".format(age, size),
    cat_string_description
)
```

but, I get

"error: invalid group reference"

and, if I try

```
return pattern.sub(
    r"\1\2\3",
    cat_string_description
)
```

I get

```
cat description:
 cat age: 
 cat size: 
 other properties
end cat description:
```

why I get `error: invalid group reference` ?

Comment: @OlehPrypin python 2.7

Comment: You get the invalid group reference because `r"\1{}\2{}\3".format('30', '40') -> '\\130\\240\\3'` and you don't have group number `130` nor number `240`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with

```
return pattern.sub(
    r"\g<1>{}\g<2>{}\g<3>".format('30', '40'),
    cat_string_description
)
```

Comment: Why are you calling `.format`? You can simply do: `r"\g<1>30<2>40\g<3>`

Comment: because the `30` and `40` are variables.